# Typescript error when changing property of object dynamically

Tags: typescript, types

I'm having trouble when I try to update an Object's property based on a dynamic variable. I've checked a few more answers on stackoverflow but couldn't manage to find a solution.

```js
export interface Bikes {
  totals: Array<number>;
}

interface Products {
  cars:  Cars;
  bikes:  Bikes;
}

export interface RawData {
    products: Products
}

demo( data: RawData ) {
  // data.products contains both "cars" and "bikes" properties.
  for (var type in data.products) { 
    for (var product in data.products[type].totals) {// <-- error here
                        -------------
     ....
   }
}
```

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Products'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Products'.

I've also tried using:

```js
export interface RawData {
    products: keyof Products
}
```

And then the error appears on data.products[type]**.totals**

> Property 'bikes' does not exist on type 'string'.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the `for-in` loop? And what is the definition of the `Cars` and `Bikes` types?

Comment: I've updated the question. It loops through the different product types coming from the JSON data. (bikes and cars)

Answer (score 2):

In your case, variable `type` is infered to `string`.

TS disallows you to use `string` type as index of `RawData['products']` type.

If you want to assure TS that you can do it, you have two ways:

**1) Make type assertion**

```js
  function demo(data: RawData) {
    for (const type in data.products) {
       // explicitly define type for `type` varable
      for (const product in data.products[type as keyof RawData['products']]) { // ok

      }
    }
  }
```

**2) Make Products indexable**

```js
  interface Products {
    cars: Cars;
    bikes: Bikes;
    [prop: string]: Cars | Bikes
  }
```

**UPDATE**

```js
  interface Bikes {
    totals: Array<number>;
  }

  type Mix = { foo: 'a' };

  type Products = {
    cars: Cars;
    bikes: Bikes;
    mix?: Mix;
  }
  type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

  type MakeIndexed<T> = T & { [prop: string]: Values<T> }


  interface RawData {
    products: MakeIndexed<Products>
  }

  function demo(data: RawData) {
    for (const type in data.products) {
      for (const product in data.products[type]) { // ok

      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: If I have an optional property inside the Products interface, such as `mix:? Mix` then adding your last line (`[prop: string]: Cars | Bikes`) shows me this error `Property 'mix' of type 'Cars | Bikes | undefined' is not assignable to string index type 'Cars | Bikes'.ts`

Comment: `Cannot find name 'Values'.ts(2304)` It seems Values is not defined on your example.

Comment: You should not look for Values.ts.
In my example, Values - is just utility type